# How to get SQLCMD to output errors and warnings only?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sqlcmd

How can you get SQLCMD, when executing a SQL script file, to just output any errors or warnings it encounters?

I essentially dont want information based messages to be output.

Comment: Hmm, in another app we could redirect error output with `2> Err.txt`, but it looks like `SQLCMD` does not split its output.

Comment: @JonofAllTrades By default yes, SQLCMD sends _all_ output to **stdout**. However, you can instruct SQLCMD to send errors to **stderr** via the `-r0` command-line switch, in which case they can be redirected to a file using `2>`, or they can be displayed while regular messages are redirected via `>`. Please see my [answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20096/how-to-get-sqlcmd-to-output-errors-and-warnings-only/110739#110739) for details.

Answer (score 5):

By default, **SQLCMD** sends all non-error messages and error messages to **stdout**. Hence, attempting to redirect output won't help.

The first thing you need to do in order to get only one or the other type of messages (error or non-error) is to tell **SQLCMD** to separate them by sending the error messages (severity level 11 or higher) to **stderr**. You do this by using the `-r` command-line switch, specifying `0` as the option for that switch (i.e. `-r0`). At this point there is no visible difference in terms of running SQLCMD and seeing messages of any type displayed on the screen.

The next part is to filter out the regular messages going to **stdout**.  This can be done by redirecting the **stdout** messages to somewhere via `>`, but where to? You could do `> file.txt`, but I doubt you want a file of the messages that you didn't want to begin with. Fortunately, DOS has the `NUL` keyword (that is *not* a typeo: it has one `L`, not two) that works like `/dev/null` in Unix. Meaning you can use the following to redirect output to nowhere: `> NUL`.

The following will execute the `PRINT` command and show no output as no errors are generated, and no file is created that would contain the output of the `PRINT` command:

```
CD %TEMP%

SQLCMD -E -Q "print 1;" -r0 > NUL
```

But the following displays an error message as those are not being redirected to `NUL`:

```
CD %TEMP%

SQLCMD -E -Q "print a;" -r0 > NUL
```

Returns:

```
Msg 128, Level 15, State 1, Server DALI, Line 1
The name "a" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants,
constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.
```

Answer (score 1):

The following will work:

`sqlcmd -U user -P pass -S Server -Q "sp_who" -r0 1> test.log`

The output from the query will be put into the log and nothing is printed on the screen.

More details at the [MSDN article on sqlcmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx).

Comment: This does not actually work according to the requested "I essentially dont want **information based messages** to be output" (my emphasis). The issue is that `-r1` sends _all_ messages to **stderr**, including `PRINT` and `RAISERROR('', 10, 1)` messages. You need to use `-r0` to keep those regular info messages going to **stdout** such that they are redirected to **test.log**.

Comment: @srutzky Thanks, modified my answer to reflect your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Found this on SQLServerCentral

```
sqlcmd -E -i"install.sql" -r1 2> install-err.log 1> install.log
```

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic536968-146-1.aspx

Comment: This does not actually work according to the requested "I essentially dont want **information based messages** to be output" (my emphasis). The issue is that `-r1` sends _all_ messages to **stderr**, including `PRINT` and `RAISERROR('', 10, 1)` messages. You need to use `-r0` to keep those regular info messages going to **stdout** such that they are redirected to **install.log**.